# Use javax.mail send email with google oauth

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, google-oauth

I'm trying to send email by using javax.mail and Google OAuth. My workflow is:

User login with Google OAuth, get access_token, send the token to java back-end server, then use javax.mail to authenticate and send email by email & token, instead of email & password. However, after I set the token in props, I still get the invalid username and password error. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.put(OAuth2SaslClientFactory.OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP, accessToken);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
mimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
mimeMessage.setSubject("test");
mimeMessage.setContent("xxx", "text/html");


SMTPTransport transport = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", myEmailAddress, "");
transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pass the access token as the password.](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2)

Comment: Thanks Bill. However, I tried this method, but it's not working only by using these lines of code. Any one who read the post, please check my github project. I have already got it work and tested.

Comment: That's because your dependencies list both JavaMail 1.5.5 and JavaMail 1.4.7.  It must be picking up 1.4.7, which is why it's not working.